# Obtaining type of elements in array c++

Tags: c++

It is easy to obtain the size of an array:

```
myarray.size()
```

Is there a function (say, type) way to obtain the type of the elements in the array?:

```
myarray.type()
```

Or must I use more mundane options?

Comment: Can you show a situation where you would need this? Also, look at `decltype`.

Comment: I don't really need this - I just wanted to know, because then it would make the array class as a whole easier to remember.

Comment: You do realize that a type is primarily a compile-time thing? The compiler reasons about it, you can even juggle it around using templates, but it's not a value you can pass around at runtime or store in a variable (`typeof` is the closest thing, but even that is pretty different). Do you want to do things like declare a variable of the element type, or (say) print the type's name?

Comment: thanks - I guess I didn't think too hard about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `value_type` trait, as for any STL container.

```
#include <array>

int main()
{
    typedef std::array<int, 5> my_array_type;
    my_array_type::value_type x = 2;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Yes, a type trait is of course a "compilation thing", this trait remains useful, its worth remembering that it exists on std::array.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't indicate what class you're using for your array object, so strictly speaking there is no way to answer your question.

Take a look at the reference documentation for std::array from the C++ standard template library.  There you can find a reference to the `value_type` member -- this gives you an indication of the type of object in the collection.

Comment: `decltype(*std::begin(container))` works well though